# Django equivalent of Rail's has_one through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, relationships, has-one

Is there something equivalent to `has_one :through` in Django?

I have `User`, `Company`, and `CompanyMember` models. `CompanyMember` has  foreign keys to `User` and `Company`. A `User` can belong to a `Company` through the `CompanyMember` model. Assume `User` is unique in `CompanyMember`

In Rails, this relationship would look something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company_member
  has_one :company, :through => :company_member
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_members
end

class CompanyMember < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And I would be able to use `user.company` to get the user's company.

In Django, I have my models like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class CompanyMember(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    is_company_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Is it possible to get `user.company` to work like in Rails? I also like to be able to use it in queryset filters, like `user__company=company`.

Comment: Seeing that python code next to ruby code only reminds me how ugly python is.

Comment: @Donato Heh... was just thinking the same thing, but in reverse. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='CompanyMember')

class CompanyMember(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

**Update:**

To access the company for a given user, you can now do this:

```
myuser.company_set.first()
```

You probably don't want to change the built-in User model. But you can add your own convenience methods/properties fairly easily by using a proxy model, ex:

```
class MyUser(User):
    @property
    def company(self):
        return self.company_set.first()
    class Meta:
        proxy=True
```

Then, any time you would normally use a User object, use MyUser instead and it will have that convenience property for you. Ex:

```
MyUser.objects.get(id=123)
```

will be the same record as

```
User.objects.get(id=123)
```

but you'll have the extra convenience methods/properties on the object. Ex:

```
myuser = MyUser.objects.get(id=123)
myuser.company
```

Comment: FWIW, it is not necessary to provide a model for the "middle" table of an M2M, this is only needed if you plan to store data *about* the relationship.

Comment: Thank you, I've read through the documentation. Indeed I am storing extra data. So to access the company from the user I would have to write `user.company_set.first()`? I guess that would work but really it would be nicer if it were just `user.company` since in my case a user can only belong to one company, and this is enforced with the unique key on `user` in `CompanyMember`.

Comment: you can use user.company, but you have to use OneToOneField in django. You are using ForeignKey, which is equivalent to many to one